# Accessing Phones GPS settings using javascript

Tags: javascript, google-maps, web-applications, gps

Im working on a geo-location web app using javascript and the google maps api-v3. I was wondering if it is possible to check if the user is connected to their GPS and if not, navigate the user to his or her phones gps settings?? I know it's possible to do in a native iphone/android app but not sure about javascript...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid this is not possible. The only option to get the location is to use the standard javascript [Geolocation API](http://dev.w3.org/geo/api/spec-source.html).

Comment: Thought so. Thanks for the confirmation. Im guessing its probably also not possible to access different parts of a users phone using javascript?

Comment: With javascript you cannot directly address phone-specific hardware. However you could create a native app using web-technologies. If you want to take that route you could take a look at phonegap.com. But in my opinion: if you want to use hardware features of a phone, develop a native app for that phone.